# HTML Certificate

Tags: html, certificate, responsive

I need to create an HTML certificate page it should be responsive and the user can print the certificate by clicking ctrl+p which only captures the certificate not other content of the page. Can I get the reference for this?

Comment: You provide to less information. What have you tried already and do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Design certificate with **inline CSS**. for reference read about "Emailer".